# Using "rewrite" inside non-top-level goal requires auxiliary function?

Tags: scope, proof, agda, rewriting

I have an Agda formalisation of pi-calculus with de Bruijn indices. Most of the setup is irrelevant to my problem, so I'll use empty types for renamings `Ren` and actions, and simply postulate a basic renaming `sucᴿ`, plus some useful operations and properties of renamings.

```
module Concur where

   open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
   -- de Bruijn indices:
   open import Data.Fin using () renaming (Fin to Name; module Fin to Name)
   open import Data.Nat as Nat using () renaming (ℕ to Cxt; module ℕ to Cxt)

   -- empty types will do here
   data Ren : Cxt → Cxt → Set where
   data Action (Γ : Cxt) : Set where

   postulate
      _∘_ : ∀ {Γ₁ Γ₂ Γ₃} → Ren Γ₂ Γ₃ → Ren Γ₁ Γ₂ → Ren Γ₁ Γ₃
      -- push a renaming under a binder
      suc : ∀ {Γ Γ′} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Ren (Cxt.suc Γ) (Cxt.suc Γ′)
      -- successor function on ℕ, qua renaming
      sucᴿ : ∀ {Γ} → Ren Γ (Cxt.suc Γ)
      -- apply a renaming to an action
      _*ᴬ_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Action Γ → Action Γ′
      -- here's a useful property
      suc-comm : ∀ {Γ Γ′} (ρ : Ren Γ Γ′) (a : Action Γ) → 
                 suc ρ *ᴬ (sucᴿ *ᴬ a) ≡ sucᴿ *ᴬ (ρ *ᴬ a)
```

Now I'll define processes, transitions and the application of a renaming to process, but limiting myself just to two kinds of process and a single kind of transition.

```
   data Proc (Γ : Cxt) : Set where
      Ο : Proc Γ
      ν_ : Proc (Cxt.suc Γ) → Proc Γ

   data _—[_]→_ {Γ} : Proc Γ → Action Γ → Proc Γ → Set where
      ν_ : ∀ {P R} {a : Action Γ} → P —[ sucᴿ *ᴬ a ]→ R → ν P —[ a ]→ ν R

   infixl 0 _—[_]→_

   -- Apply a renaming to a process.
   _*_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Proc Γ → Proc Γ′
   ρ * Ο = Ο
   ρ * (ν P) = ν (suc ρ * P)
```

Here's my problem. I want to use my useful property `suc-comm` to show that I can lift an arbitrary renaming `ρ` to a transition. In the `ν`-binder case, this involves recursing into the sub-transition `E`, using `suc` to push the renaming under the binder, and the `suc-comm` lemma to show that things commute in the right way.

```
   -- A transition survives an arbitrary renaming.
   _*¹_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ P R} {a : Action Γ} (ρ : Ren Γ Γ′) →
          P —[ a ]→ R → ρ * P —[ ρ *ᴬ a ]→ ρ * R
   ρ *¹ (ν_ {a = a} E) rewrite sym (suc-comm ρ a) =
      ν {!suc ρ *¹ E!} -- rewriting here doesn't help
```

Unfortunately, and as indicated above, using `rewrite` to apply the lemma doesn't help because the goal isn't of a suitable type until I'm inside the `ν`. But I can only apply `rewrite` at the top level of a function body. So I seem to need an auxiliary function, so that I can `rewrite` in the correct context:

```
   _*²_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ P R} {a : Action Γ} (ρ : Ren Γ Γ′) →
          P —[ a ]→ R → ρ * P —[ ρ *ᴬ a ]→ ρ * R
   aux : ∀ {Γ Γ′ P R} (a : Action Γ) (ρ : Ren Γ Γ′) →
         P —[ sucᴿ *ᴬ a ]→ R → suc ρ * P —[ sucᴿ *ᴬ (ρ *ᴬ a) ]→ suc ρ * R
   ρ *² (ν_ {a = a} E) = ν aux a ρ E
   aux a ρ E rewrite sym (suc-comm ρ a) = suc ρ *² E
```

Indeed this works, but it seems a bit awkward. Am I missing a trick here? Is there a way to avoid the auxiliary function, and somehow make use of the lemma inside the earlier goal?

Comment: Well, you could always do it explicitly using `subst`. You don't need auxiliary function, but it is no less awkward, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inline `rewrite`, but it's still awkward:

```
 _*¹_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ P R} {a : Action Γ} (ρ : Ren Γ Γ′) →
        P —[ a ]→ R → ρ * P —[ ρ *ᴬ a ]→ ρ * R
 ρ *¹ (ν_ {a = a} E) with suc ρ *ᴬ (sucᴿ *ᴬ a) | suc-comm ρ a | suc ρ *¹ E
 ... | ._ | refl | E' = ν E'
```

Or introduce `suc ρ *¹ E` first and then rewrite:

```
 _*¹_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ P R} {a : Action Γ} (ρ : Ren Γ Γ′) →
        P —[ a ]→ R → ρ * P —[ ρ *ᴬ a ]→ ρ * R
 ρ *¹ (ν_ {a = a} E) with suc ρ *¹ E
 ... | E' rewrite suc-comm ρ a = ν E'
```